# No signature of method: static io.restassured.internal.http.URIBuilder.encode()

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

> I am trying to check basic rest assured get method and getting below
>   error. Using the below version: rest-assured-4.2.0-dist.zip.I am trying to check basic rest assured get method and getting below error. Using the below version: rest-assured-4.2.0-dist.zipI am trying to check basic rest assured get method and getting below error. Using the below version: rest-assured-4.2.0-dist.zip

```
package restSuite;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.*;

public class basics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://qa1.services.nissanusa.com";
        given().
        param("division","IN").
        param("vehicleType","N").
        param("modelYear","2019").
        param("modelLineCode","X30").
        param("countryCode","US").
        param("languageCode","US").
        param("currency","USD").
        header("Authorization","Bearer 08433244-6fc5-3b24-9c21-0e3ee01a3ed5").
        when().
        get("/dealerstock/vehicle/1.0/needsAssessmentModelDetails").
        then().assertThat().statusCode(200);



    }

}
```

**I am getting the below error after executing the service**

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static io.restassured.internal.http.URIBuilder.encode() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [dealerstock, UTF-8]
    Possible solutions: hashCode()
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1503)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1489)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.encode(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1823)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$_partiallyApplyPathParams_closure36.doCall(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1752)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1089)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.inject(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:5466)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$336.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.partiallyApplyPathParams(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1755)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.newFilterContext(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1063)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1653)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1661)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
```

Answer (score 1):

The above issue can be resolved by adding below httpcore dependency or Jar in your Automation Framework.

Dependency for POM :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.6</version>
</dependency>


httpcore-4.4.6.jar  ( You can download this jar from Maven repository)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in my maven build running any test that calls an http method. What worked for me was to add to my classpath (via Maven dependencies) the latest version of every non-optional library that is listed as a dependency for the library here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.2.0

Note: apache.commons.logging is required but not listed on that page.

The dependency that really made the difference is the junit 5 libraries. My test ran successfully when I replaced junit 4 with 5 and configured my IDE (eclipse) to run using that version. Here is the dependencies element of my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/xml-path -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup/tagsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>tagsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```